# Typescript 'Missing semicolon' error when casting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a `Parsing error: Missing semicolon.` whenever I try casting an object. The following is an example where this happens:

```
return (
    <>
        {tracks.map((track) => {
            const arcTrack = track as ArcTrack;
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>{arcTrack.radius}</span>
                    <span>{arcTrack.angle}</span>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </>
);
```

And the error points at:

```
const arcTrack = track as ArcTrack;
                      ^
```

I'm using React and it's a .tsx file. I'm not using Babel or ESLint. Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to transpile tsx into JS?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm just using `"jsx": "react-jsx"` on my `tsconfig.json`

Comment: You'd need a semi-colon for your map function; would that be it? I don't use this kind of rendering.

Comment: May you make a more complete example? Right now it's hard to know if the error is what's actually wrong.

Comment: `const arcTrack: ArcTrack = track;`?